# Trapping ctrl-c within stack's docker

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm developing with stack within a docker container. However I need to use ctrl+c within my container without it getting killed. Is there a way to pass a config into stack's docker in order for ctrl+c not to be intercepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: I implemented Stack's docker ctrl-C/signal handling.  It was very tricky to get it to behave in a somewhat reasonable way for most common use cases, because Docker does weird things with ctrl-C and signals.

I'd suggest if you need this level of sophistication, you might be better off creating the Docker container yourself and then running Stack in it, rather than having Stack do it.